# Copy excel icon set on another sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I created a series of cells with icon set.  How can copy the last cell to another sheet including the icon set it currently have?.  When i copied the last cell to another sheet, it does not preserve the same icon set.

Answer (score 0):

With an in-built formula it can't be done without using something like VBA as well.